# How do you deal with variable input sizes with an encoder-decoder net with skip connections in Keras?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, image-segmentation, convolutional-neural-network

I am currently getting into image segmentation with Keras, and I am using an encoder-decoder type as in the image below.
[image: Encoder-Decoder with skip connections]

My problem is that applying a `MaxPooling2D` layer of size (2,2) cannot be reliably reversed by using an `UpSampling2D` layer of size (2,2), as the input and output sizes do not match if the input dimensions are odd. The same problem arises with a `Conv2D` layer with a stride >1 which I want to "reverse" with a `Conv2DTranspose` layer. This leads to the problem that the skip connections sometimes connect layers of differing sizes such that I cannot concatenate these layers.

Is any canonical way to deal with this problem in Keras, while maintaining skip connections and allowing arbitrary input sizes?